# Has a scheduled passenger flight ever stalled because of shifting cargo?

Tags: safety, commercial-aviation, accidents, stall, accident-investigation

Has any scheduled commercial passenger - not cargo - flight ever experienced a stall due to cargo shifting, like the [National Airlines Flight 102](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Airlines_Flight_102) did, back in 2013?

*Please note I am specifically asking about scheduled airline flights with passengers on board, i.e. not cargo flights. No incidents involving tanks or other military equipment.*

Comment: [Possibly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_Bandundu_Filair_Let_L-410_crash)

Comment: National Airlines *is* a commercial operator, they aren't part of the military

Comment: @Pondlife Yes, but this wasn't a commercial *flight*., it was a military one.

Comment: @Cloud It was a commercial flight, they were just carrying military equipment. Just like putting military personnel on a domestic flight doesn't make it a military one. It was a commercial operator on a commercial flight.

Comment: As Ron said, that flight was a commercial one. I don't know exactly what you mean here, but are you asking about a scheduled airline flight with passengers on board, i.e. not a cargo flight?

Comment: National Airlines was/is a civilian Part 121 or 125 carrier. The military regularly contracts with civilian carriers for movement of cargo and personnel, but the flights are commercial flights and are not distinguishable from other commercial flying insofar as the rules. I flew many such flights, and occasionally the disparity between military rules and FAA rules did cause confusion. Both sets of rules are more or less restrictive than the other depending on what area of operations you're talking about. Military commanders can waive some rules. Airline managers cannot waive FAA rules.

Comment: I notice that the link in the OP does not include the video of the crash. Go to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qPngBazzce4 for that. It is dramatic, to say the least. Also, on a far more minor note, cargo shifts to happen, but they're usually just a single ULD and easily handled. See the last paragraphs of http://terryliittschwager.com/Journal/1999-01-23.html for one such shift.

Comment: This accident had more to do with the cargo shift taking out the horizontal stabilizer jackscrew than the actual shift in weight changing the plane's center of gravity.

Comment: @Pondlife Please understand what I'm asking. Obviously most commercial flights do not carry tanks on them... so for the sake of clarity I have edited the question. Please feel free to re-edit if this isn't good enough

Comment: @Terry But I must admit, I enjoyed the read, especially the " put-your-head-between-your-legs (and kiss your ass goodbye as the saying goes) drill" xD

Comment: @Terry I read the whole thing and think I will now binge read all of your journals :)

Comment: @Terry the video is not in the question because it is not really needed to understand the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, a [LET-410 crashed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_Bandundu_Filair_Let_L-410_crash) in the DR Congo, apparently because a crocodile escaped. Passengers trying to escape the animal apparently caused enough of a load shift to result in a crash.

Not a shift, but [Air Midwest Flight 5481](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Midwest_Flight_5481) crashed due to a combination of a  weight and balance error coupled with a misrigged elevator.

In general, it's harder to have a significant load shift on a passenger aircraft since it's easy to check the distribution of passenger loads, people are well restrained by seat backs, and unless something else is catastrophically wrong (fire), passengers don't all get up and move to one side of the aircraft.

Answer (score 3):

If you include tailstrikes in your definition, then yes. There has been at least [one case](https://aviation-safety.net/database/record.php?id=20090901-0) in Italy involving a takeoff with an A320 where the aircraft was loaded without any baggage in CP 1. Although it did not involve a shifting ULD, the improper loading did contribute to the incident.